# Unity UI objects invisible

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a lot of UI elements inside a canvas. I then moved the UI objects out of the canvas and deleted the empty canvas. 
 Now, if I create a new canvas and move those UI objects into that new canvas, the UI is invisible. 
 I can't  undo my deletion of the old canvas.

Is there anyway to restore the visibility of the UI objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your canvas is probably setup differently than the old one. Fiddle with the canvas setup and make a note of the new settings. There is no reason you can’t drag objects between canvases so it must be a setup issue.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your UI elements are children of the new canvas.